# android: Not able to find @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Hi in my android studio project this is always red: @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar

and this:

@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar
[image]

I have tried everything but still now able to solve this. please help me

and by styles.xml is

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/lightBorder</item>


</style>

<style name="deafultSpinner" parent="android:Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


    <!--            new             -->

    <style name="logo_img">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/logo</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/logo_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/logo_height</item>
    </style>



    <style name="logo_tv">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/logo_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:text">RhythmCor</item>
    </style>





    <style name="logo_img2">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">50dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/logo_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/logo_height</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>


    <style name="logo_img3">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/logo_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/logo_height</item>
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/logo</item>
    </style>


    <style name="status_img">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">100dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">@dimen/statusIcon_width</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">@dimen/statusIcon_height</item>
    </style>


    <style name="logo_tv2">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/screen_text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
    </style>


    <style name="logo_desc_tv">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/normal_text</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/small_line_spacing</item>
    </style>


    <style name="logo_desc_tv2">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/normal_text</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/small_line_spacing</item>
    </style>


    <style name="logo_desc_tv3">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/small_text</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/small_line_spacing</item>
    </style>




    <style name="welcome_tv1">
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/welcome_text1</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:text">Welcome!</item>
    </style>


    <style name="welcome_tv2">
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">25dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/welcome_text2</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:lineSpacingExtra">@dimen/normal_line_spacing</item>
        <item name="android:text">Keep track of your health\nwith RhythmCor</item>
    </style>



    <style name="welcome_footer_btns">
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:layout_margin">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/welcome_btn_text</item>
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    </style>



    <style name="external_buttons">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">24dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    </style>


    <style name="external_buttons1">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">-10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:background">@null</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    </style>


    <style name="external_buttons2">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">40dp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:padding">12dp</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

and my dependencies in build.gradle is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: post your `res/values/style.xml`

Comment: could you post your build.gradle

Comment: done please check updated answer

Comment: @AmitBhandari please check now

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

        <!--  Toolbar style -->
        <item name="toolbarStyle">@style/MyToolBarStyle</item>

        <!--  Spinner style -->
        <item name="spinnerStyle">@style/MySpinner</item>

        <!-- colorPrimary is used for the default action bar background -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>

        <!-- colorPrimaryDark is used for the status bar -->
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>

        <!--
         colorAccent is used as the default value for colorControlActivated,
         which is used to tint widgets -->
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>

    </style>
```

Comment: use themes.xml for application theme and use style.xml for styling :)

Answer (score 0):

I only had to update my android studio and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Use this @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar   replace of @style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar  in xml coding.